# Can I limit Sentry’s error reporting to just my own code

Tags: javascript, sdk, sentry

### Problem Description：

I am developing a JavaScript sdk package, and connecting to sentry to monitor the exception of the sdk. Unfortunately, sentry will also capture errors other than the sdk code

As follows, my sdk is the client directory, and I use this sdk package in the demo. If there is an exception in the demo, sentry will also capture it
[image]

### desired result：

Only catch exceptions of the current sdk. Exclusion of demo

## Supplementary Instructions：

[image]
I thought about allowUrls and denyUrls but I couldn't, because the sdk generated a bunch of hash values after the demo was packaged.

Can you give me an idea? grateful